What was the newest chess piece
Out of the all the chess pieces in standard chess, which one(s) was created most recently?

The question itself is a misconception, so to say: chess is a very old game and it developed over time into what it is today. The pieces themselves are all there as far as we can trace them back in time but their abilities changed over time.
In about the 12th to 15th century chess rules changed in Europe in a number of ways and all those changes made the game faster and less static than the Arabian chess: castling was "invented", the bishop got its ability to move in today's form (from the former alfil), the same goes for the queen and the double-move of the pawns were adopted as well as the en-passant rule.
This last rule change – double step of the pawn and en passant – is already mentioned in Ruy Lopez' book Libro de la invencion liberal y arte del juego del axedrez (1561), but it is universally accepted only since 1880, when the Italian rules were changed too (see The Oxford Companion to Chess, David V. Hooper and Kenneth Whyld, Oxford University Press, 2nd ed. 1992, p 124f).
So, arguably, the pawn is the "newest piece", as the pawn is the one which moving underwent the most recent change.

With the logic of bakunin above (on which I agree), one is tempted to say "the king", as castling rules also unified very lately (Wiki: 17th century), and to add some trollolo, only in the 20th, the "Staugaard" loophole was closed.

For context (since the page is in German): the Staugaard loophole is vertical castling between a pawn promoted to a rook and the king. This is "textually" allowed under certain rulesets which don't explicitly forbid it; FIDE rules (codified around 1930) explicitly state that castling must occur on the "player's first rank".

The "allowing" rules are: Neither rook nor king were moved during the game. In between rook and king are no other pieces. The king is not in check nor will be in check on any field it may cross or end on during the maneuver. Technically this allows for "vertical castling".

THX for the relink, if I weren't so lazy and hasty, I would have found the E version of the reference myself :-)

Since vertical castling was always a troll, one might argue for the pawn, because the details of promotion and en passant are much more recent than castling.

The Queen is the newest chess piece, gaining her abilities somewhere around the 15th century.

Marilyn Yalom's "Birth of the Chess Queen," might be a curious read if you are interested in the historical development of the queen's presence and role in chess. Teaser question: if chess was historically meant to represent war, why is the queen (a woman) there, and why is she the most powerful piece?
